# Where have XmlCsvReader and SgmlReader from XmlTools from gotdotnet.com gone to?

Tags: .net, html, xml, csv

Once upon a time there was a great microsofts dotnet site www.gotdotnet.com with lots of dotnet sources and examples.

One of these were the [XmlTools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687702.aspx) with interisting classes like XmlCsvReader/writer (= csv 2 xml converter) , SgmlReader (can be used to transform sgml, html to xml) and XmlPrettyPrinter. The documentation is still online in msdn and there are many references to in it today on the internet.

Msdn-downloads for those link to gotdotnet.com.

Since www.gotdotnet.com went offline in 2006 or 2007 so the **download links are broken**.
Does anybody know **if these xmltools are still available somewhere**?

update:

- @Darin Dimitrov: SgmlReader is [available on archive.msdn.microsoft.com](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SgmlReader)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [SgmlReader](http://developer.mindtouch.com/en/docs/SgmlReader). And the [archived one](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SgmlReader). <strike>[XmlCsvReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302293.aspx) is still available on MSDN.</strike> You may also take a look at [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/).

Comment: @k3b, oops, you are correct. The link for XmlCsvReader no longer works.